# Skip an iteration if time limit exceeds PYTHON

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x

I'm working with proxies on request library for my project.Depending on the proxy used, each request takes different (unpredictable) time.

```
for proxy in proxyList:
    r=requests.post(url, proxies=proxy, data=payload)
```

If a certain request takes more than certain time,I want to skip it and move on to the next.How can this be done?
EDIT : Using timeout parameter raises an exception.Of course,I can get my work done by Exception handling.But I wanted it in a more general sense..like what if I'm not talking about requests ..suppose there is statement whose time can't be pre-defined?! Is there any way to move on to next iteration?

Comment: Did you check the docs for Requests?  `post()` takes a timeout parameter.

Comment: @Jkdc it raises an exception.Of course,I can get my work done by Exception handling.But I wanted it in a more general sense..like what if I'm not talking about requests ..suppose there is statement whose time can't be pre-defined?! Is there any way to move on to next iteration?

Answer (score 1):

On Mac/UNIX systems, you can raise a custom exception after a certain period of time like this:

```
import signal

class TimeoutException(Exception):   # custom exception
    pass

def timeout_handler(signum, frame):   # raises exception when signal sent
    raise TimeoutException

# Makes it so that when SIGALRM signal sent, it calls the function timeout_handler, which raises your exception
signal.signal(signal.SIGALRM, timeout_handler)

# Start the timer. Once 5 seconds are over, a SIGALRM signal is sent.
for proxy in proxyList:
    signal.alarm(5)
    try:
        r=requests.post(url, proxies=proxy, data=payload)
    except TimeoutException:
        pass
```

Basically, you're creating a custom exception that's raised when the after the time limit is up (i.e., the `SIGALRM` is sent). You can of course tweak the time limit.

**More simply** in your case, you can use the timeout parameter, as far as I can tell. As the [documentation](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/) says:

> You can tell Requests to stop waiting for a response after a given number of seconds with the timeout parameter. Nearly all production code should use this parameter in nearly all requests. Failure to do so can cause your program to hang indefinitely [...]

so your code would end up looking like

```
for proxy in proxyList:
    r=requests.post(url, proxies=proxy, data=payload, timeout=1)
```

(Timeout parameter is in seconds.)

Comment: Is there any way to do it on Windows ?

Comment: OP didn't ask for a solution in MAC or UNIX. Consider most people use Windows, please give us a solution in Windows.

Answer (score 1):

Add `timeout=10` (for example) to your `post` call.

```
r = requests.post(url, proxies=proxy, data=payload, timeout=10)
```

You could have answered the question yourself with e.g. `help(requests.post)` or by looking at the [documentation](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#timeouts).

Comment: I'm think this will raise an exception if it times out. http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#timeouts . Also, if it's waiting on a download, the timeout won't work.

Comment: What do you mean "if it's waiting on a download"? All HTTP requests are HTTP requests, there is no special download mode.

Comment: `timeout is not a time limit on the entire response download; rather, an exception is raised if the server has not issued a response for timeout seconds (more precisely, if no bytes have been received on the underlying socket for timeout seconds)` So if a connection is established but is sending a large amount of data the timeout will not trigger.

Comment: That should still work fine for a site that's not responding at all.

Comment: I agree.  My understanding of OP's problem was the site N is taking X seconds to respond and OP doesn't want to wait around for X.